# How can I bind an attribute from db table to combobox WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Here's my combo box:

```
<ComboBox
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="125,110,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="120"
                SelectedValue="{Binding LotNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding LotNumber}"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.583,2" Height="18" />
```

Here's my property for LotNumber:

```
private string lotNumber;
public string LotNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return lotNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            lotNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LotNumber");
        }
    }
```

Right now lot number attribute is under my lotInformation table.

E.g. (excerpt of class, class has another properties)

```
public class LotInformation
{
    [XmlAttribute("lot_number")]
    public string lot_number { get; set; }
```

}

So, my dbset is:

```
public DbSet<LotInformation> LotInformation {get;set;}
```

The binding for combobox is empty. Nothing gets binded... I'm not sure why. Should I be using ComboBox_Loaded?

Basically, I just want to display all the lot numbers that are currently present inside the database.

Comment: Your ItemsSource needs to be a collection of strings (lot numbers) if you want to bind to the lot number.  You should use MVVM and bind a ViewModel to your view.  The view would then consist of a DataTemplate for your ViewModel, and would contain the above code.

Comment: So, I am (At least I think) using MVVM. So, in my View, let's say LotView, is the XAML above. In my LotViewModel, that's where I have my property. It might have to do with a collection of strings like you said because strangely, I was able to bind a LotNumber to a textBox using Text="{Binding LotNumber}" (only one number that pertains to a file a user uploaded) but I can't bind the lot number to the combo box. This might be because I need to load it on the view from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding `ItemsSource` to `LotNumber`, which is a string. The expected value for `ItemsSource` is a collection of objects to display in the dropdown.

Since `string` is not "a collection of objects", your binding is probably failing.

What you want to do is create a collection of available values (use a `List<string>` if your collection is static, or an `ObservableCollection<string>` if the collection is dynamic and can be changed at runtime) and bind your `ItemsSource` property to that

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllAvailableLotNumbers}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding LotNumber}" />
```

Comment: So I have to create a list from the values already stored in db and keep updating the list as the data grows? Let me explain how I'm getting this data. The user is uploading an Xml file that is deserialized and lot_number is just a string that occurs once everytime someone uploads an new xml data file. In my class, should I be changing it to a list or keep it as a string? Right now, I created a new lot number list property but it is empty and that's why when I bind to the list and the specific item, nothing happens.

Comment: @KalaJ If your database contains a list of all available lot numbers that should be displayed in the ComboBox, then you will want to retrieve that information, store it in a `List<string>` (or `ObservableCollection<string>` if users can update that list while the program is running), and bind that collection of available values to the `ItemsSource` property. The `ItemsSource` property specifies what items are available in the ComboBox dropdown, while `SelectedItem` is the item in the list which is selected.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!! I got it working. I retrieved the data using LINQ and then I added it to a list. I used a combination of your solution and rajibdotnet's solution below. I am wondering though what's the difference between SelectedItem and DisplayMemberPath? I used DisplayMemberPath instead. Thanks! :D

Comment: @KalaJ `SelectedItem` refers to the item in the `ItemsSource` that is set as Selected. `DisplayMemberPath` is the name of the property you want displayed on the screen for each item. For example, if you had bound your `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to a list of `KeyValuePair` objects, you could set the `DisplayMemberPath` to "Value" to make it display the `.Value` property, or to "Key" to make it display the `.Key` property.

Comment: I have one more side question, if I want to be able to select an item from a combobox and then have my datagrid populate with the other columns  in my db that are fall under the lot number I selected, how does the binding work? How does DataGrid know about Combobox selection? Thanks again.

Comment: @KalaJ You'd add a change event to the combobox that filters the datagrid based on whatever is selected. Depending on your application structure, you can either use a UI SelectionChange event, or a model/viewmodel PropertyChange event. If you have problems figuring it out or finding examples with Google, just post a new question with what you are attempting, what you've tried, and your actual vs expected result.

Comment: thank you! I'll try to figure it out myself first and if I get stuck, I'll post :D

Answer (score 1):

ItemsSource is of type IEnumerable, so you need to pass it the lotInformation table(some sort of collection of LotNumbers). For binding you need to set the properties as shown :-

```
<ComboBox             
DisplayMemberPath="LotNumber"
ItemsSource="{Binding lotInformation }"/>
```

Comment: If I follow something like, I get this error: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LotInformation' property not found on 'object' ''LotViewModel' (HashCode=25277429)'. BindingExpression:Path=LotInformation; DataItem='LotViewModel' (HashCode=25277429); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: As the error says you need to create this property LotInformation. It can be of type ObservableCollection or List. Try to replicate the example provided in your code and gradually replace with your requirements. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365(v=vs.110).aspx